# Install LTE stick from Huwei 3772h on Raspberry PI with suisse telecom

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-desktop

Is there a way to use a LTE on Raspberry PI or Linux in general even if there are only .exe files on that stick?

Did anyone get a LTE stick from switzerland to work with his raspberry pi?

Comment: Not sure if this helps https://ba5ic.blogspot.com/2015/08/instal-modem-huawei-k3772-di-ubuntu.html (disagree with close as this falls under Raspberry Pi peripherals)

Comment: @Andyroo on suisse usb stick, there are only .exe files. Could it work anyway on linux?

Comment: ? Baffled - link was to person who got it working under Linux... I do not have one to test as I now use my mobile if needed but the USB/Modem switch seems valid based on the ones I had a few years ago.

Comment: but it was vodaphone, right?

Comment: Why should carrier be an issue - normally these devices are the same - just badged by the carrier and have a replaceable data sim in them.  I've seen some models where they never badged the software and the carrier label just peeled of the back...  like I say, I moved to the phone as it was simple to set a hot spot up and saved another sim to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exe files are indeed windows-only. However, many LTE sticks have Linux drivers, either released by the manufacturer, or created by the community. Ubuntu Wiki has a [list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G) of such supported sticks. You should find out what chipset your stick has (`lsusb` reports Vendor ID / Product ID which you can compare with the values from the list). If it is supported, check the "Notes" column for hints on how to get it to work. Edit your question to include details (VID/PID and what you have tried) if it still won't work, perhaps the community will be able to help.

For sticks which present themselves as mass storage (such as yours) the first step is to use [`usb_modeswitch`](https://techship.com/faq/how-to-change-usb-mode-from-storage-to-cellular-device-for-huawei-ms2372-series-usb-4g-lte-cellular-sticks-in-linux-systems/) to get it connected as a communication device instead of a thumb drive.

If it's not supported, you're most likely out of luck. I would buy a supported model and plug your SIM card in it: chances are, it will work fine on your operator's network.

Comment: The usb_modeswitch was the process in the link I gave but David seemed reluctant due to carrier differences...

Comment: @Andyroo Your link is spot on. Of course, David will have to find the correct APN configuration for his LTE provider, but the rest of the process still applies.